# C# 構造体リストのループ処理時間の質問

Tags: c#, compiler

こんにちは、自分はstructリストの実行時間をテストしていますが、なかなかわからないと面白いことを見つけた。
`TransformSystem`は構造体Vector3を操作するクラスです。メソッドMoveObjectはリストのアイテムを一個ずつ加算します。

mainメソッドには実行時間を検測します。Loop回数は50000から400000までにします。
実行する結果は以下に表示します。
50000回の結果は何も問題ありませんが、100000回以後の実行結果は全部同じになります。

私の質問は：
私のコードは問題ありますか？もし問題なければ、どうしてこんな現象が発生します？

```
public class TransformSystem
{
    private readonly List<Vector3> vectorArray;

    public TransformSystem(int capacity)
    {
        vectorArray = new List<Vector3>(capacity);
    }

    public void MoveObject(ref float x, ref float y, ref float z)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorArray.Count; i++)
        {
            var vector3 = vectorArray[i];
            vector3.x += x;
            vector3.y += y;
            vector3.z += z;
            vectorArray[i] = vector3;
        }
    }

    public void MoveObject(ref Vector3 direction)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorArray.Count; i++)
        {
            var vector = vectorArray[i];

            vector.x += direction.x;
            vector.x += direction.y;
            vector.x += direction.z;
            vectorArray[i] = vector;
        }
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 50000;
        while (count < 500000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"===========Count:{count}===========");
            Execute(count);
            count *= 2;
        }
    }

    private static void Execute(int count)
    {
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3{x = 1, y = 1, z = 1};

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        TransformSystem system = new TransformSystem(count);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("struct initialization finished. Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        system.MoveObject(ref direction);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ref struct move finished. Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);

        sw.Start();
        system.MoveObject(ref direction.x, ref direction.y, ref direction.z);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ref struct value move finished. Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

===========Count:50000===========
struct initialization finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0013711
ref struct move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0002028
ref struct value move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0004169
===========Count:100000===========
struct initialization finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000118
ref struct move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000001
ref struct value move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000002
===========Count:200000===========
struct initialization finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000061
ref struct move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000001
ref struct value move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000002
===========Count:400000===========
struct initialization finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000062
ref struct move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000001
ref struct value move finished. Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000002

Answer (score 0):

`MoveObject()` の中ではループしていません。`vectorArray` に要素を足していないので、`vectorArray.Count`は常に0です。よって、`count`の値がなんであろうと実行時間はほとんど変わらないと思われます。

Count:50000だけ遅いのは、初回のコード実行だからでしょう。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます！vectorArrayの値の与えるのは忘れてしました。